# How to display phone contacts in a listview

Tags: android

I am using contact provider to get all the all the phone numbers and names and displaying these in a listview.

Almost 4500 contacts are there in my phone.

It is taking almost 2-3 minutes to load all names and phone numbers .

Any suggestion how to reduce the loading time

Thanks
Ajeet

Comment: do not load 'em to POJOs use CursorAdapter ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) for this

```
ListAdapter list;
        list=readContacts();
        ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(list);
```

And the `readContacts()` is

```
public ListAdapter readContacts(){
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ListAdapter cd = new ArrayList<Contact_getActivity>();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phone = pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        //                         if (!Utils.isEmpty(phone)) {
                        //                             cd.add(new ContactData(id, name, phone));
                        //                         }
                    }
                    pCur.close();


                }
            }
        }
        return cd;

    }
```

Comment: BTW I recommend loading the additional info for the contacts lazily in different view after user click. I have tried the nested content provider queries and they are incredibly slow even for not so many contacts

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question but you could load a certain amount of contacts, show them in a list and load the remaining contacts in a background `thread`. When the user scrolls to the end of the list with, for example, `20` contacts, you add the newly loaded `20` contacts. I think this technique is called `paging` but I'm not sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) because they make it easy to asynchronously load data in an activity or fragment! It has many advantages as clearly mentioned in the official document [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). The doc also has an example to load contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Show only a few contacts at a time (Suppose 100 contacts).
When the user scrolls down the list, load another 100 and so on.
Just like Facebook new feed feature.
It loads a few news at one go and loads another when you scroll down further.

According to me this is the best option for optimising your application.